# Multiple thread access to a static object of a non-static class

Tags: c#, multithreading, thread-safety, concurrentdictionary

By default non-static methods have their own instance of variables for each thread when accessed via multiple threads, thus rendering them thread safe if they do not include a public variable etc.

On the other hand, variables in static methods are shared amongst threads rendering them non-thread safe by default.

Say, I have a class, having no static variables or methods whatsoever.

```
public class Profile {
    private ConcurrentDictionary<int, int> cache = 
                              new ConcurrentDictionary<int, int>();

    public AddToCache() {

    }
    public RemoveToCache() {

    }
    public DoSomethingThatShouldBeThreadSafe() {

    }
}
```

But then I create a static object from this class.

```
public static Profile objProfile = new Profile();
```

And then, objProfile is accessed with multiple threads.

The question is, are the methods of Profile class, AddToCache, RemoveFromCache and DoSomethingThatShouldBeThreadSafe, going to be thread safe or not when used through objProfile? Are their variables will be shared amongst threads, even if they are not static because the whole instance of the class is static?

Comment: You must have very special non-static methods that magically enhances all your member variables to be thread safe :)

Comment: public static Profile objProfile = new Profile();
is incorrect.

Comment: Actually I've been using this initialization for years to come. Can you clarify what you think is incorrect about it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As long as you only access the `ConcurrentDictionary<>` instance `cache`, and don't overwrite `cache` with a new instance in one of `Profile`-methods it **is threadsafe**.

Because of the second point, it's better to mark it `readonly`,

```
private readonly ConcurrentDictionary<int, int> cache = 
                     new ConcurrentDictionary<int, int>();
```

because this says that you can write this member only during instantiation of `Profile`.

---

**EDIT:**

Although the `ConcurrentDictionary<>` itself is thread-safe, you still have the problem of non-atomicity of compound operations. Let's take a look at two possible `GetFromCache()` methods.

```
int? GetFromCacheNonAtomic(int key)
{
    if (cache.ContainsKey(key))    // first access to cache
        return cache[key];         // second access to cache

    return null;
}

int? GetFromCacheAtomic(int key)
{
    int value;

    if (cache.TryGetValue(key, out value))   // single access to cache
        return value;

    return null;
}
```

only the second one is atomic, because it uses the `ConcurrentDictionary<>.TryGetValue()` method.

---

**EDIT 2 (answer to 2nd comment of Chiao):**

`ConcurrentDictionary<>` has the [`GetOrAdd()` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee378677.aspx), which takes a `Func<TKey, TValue>` delegate for non-existing values.

```
void AddToCacheIfItDoesntExist(int key)
{
    cache.GetOrAdd(key, SlowMethod);
}

int SlowMethod(int key)
{
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
    return key * 10;
}
```

Comment: It was not intended to be overwritten but you're right, you can't be too careful :) Thank you.

Comment: I always try to use Try*** methods for atomicity. But theres one thing I can't get around. Say, I have to add an object to a concurrent dictionary, but this object needs a connection to a db for a complex sp that spends a good deal of resource to return the needed value. So I go:
    if (!cache.ContainsKey(key)) {
         cache.TryAdd(int, DBOperation);
    }
Any idea will greatly be appreciated as this is about the only thing that I'm not happy about my codes on the project...

Comment: Dumb me, I've never thought of GetOrAdd()  using like this.
for(int i=0;i<int.MaxValue;i++) { Thank you ulrichb } :)

Comment: For the [GetOrAdd()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee378677(v=vs.110).aspx) is a important Remark in the documentation: `If you call GetOrAdd simultaneously on different threads, addValueFactory may be called multiple times, but its key/value pair might not be added to the dictionary for every call.`

Answer (score 1):

You seem to me to be asserting that local variables of a static method are themselves static. This is not true.

Local variables are always local for both instance and static methods and so, excluding special cases like variable capture, live on the stack. Thus they are private to each separate invocation of the method.

Answer (score 0):

Yes this should be a thread safe setup. All the functions will create their own 'copy' of the function local variables. Only when you explicitly 'touch' shared properties you'll get into problems.

However there will be only ONE cache, making the containing class static will make touching the cache NOT thread safe.